# Show wp_nav_menu() based on URL with no fallback

Tags: menus

I have specific wp menus for each url.
When I encounter a url that has no matching wp menu I dont want any nav. So far it seems if none is found it will show a default nav or pick one of the existing navs to show.

use case

http://domainnameA.com   show wp_nav_menu('domainnameA')

http://domainnameB.com   no menu exists - dont show a nav

instead I am getting Nav on Domain B that has a link to the only page that exists. If I delete the page I get no navigation but that is not a great solution.

Comment: would be great if you show us the piece of code you are using :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`has_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu)

e.g.

```
$menu_name=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$menu_name=str_ireplace("WWW.","",$menu_name);
$menu_name=str_ireplace(".","",$menu_name);
$menu_name = sanitize_title($menu_name); // sanitize!

if(has_nav_menu($menu_name)){
    wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => $menu_name));
}
```

Comment: this is close I am dynamically selecting my menus based on siteurl so I am using a variable to call the menu name. any idea if this would work with a variable instead of text?

Comment: There's absolutely no reason not, afterall 'primarymenu' is just a hardcoded string variable

Comment: `<?php
$menu_name=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$menu_name=str_ireplace("WWW.","",$menu_name);
$menu_name=str_ireplace(".","",$menu_name);
?>
<div id="nav">
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' =>$menu_name )); 
 ?>
</div>

Comment: when I tried  if(has_nav_menu($menu_name)) or if(has_nav_menu(array('menu' =>$menu_name ))) didnt seem to work

Comment: that seems like a hackish way of generating $menu_name, for one have you checked the value of $menu_name and registered a menu of that name in your functions.php? You also forgot the http://

Comment: nm there's no http:// but you still need to register the menu and add it. Simply passing any arbitary value won't work.

Comment: the effort here is to grab a custom nav based on url string - if there is an existing menu that matches the url string show it, if not show nothing.  doesn't creating a menu and naming  create it? you dont have to add each menu to the functions.php file do you?

Comment: You should register the menus in functions.php regardless, that's how the API was intended to be used by the developers. wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'menuname')); is how you would do it, but this is still inflexible, and you should register theme locations

Comment: Also will WordPress not rewrite all your permalinks to what is set as the home_url? So even if you go to domainB.com, all the links on the page will use domainA.com? ( separate question/answer to ask, not part of this question/answer )